# Mysql query find specified rows

Tags: mysql, sql

i have one table `trip_data`.Every one second i getting packets and inserting data to database.`trip_data` table contains four `fields.trip_paramid,fuel_content,creation_time&vehicle_id`.I want to select all rows in which difference between creation time is 2 minutes(Not exactly 2.Approximately 2).`trip_data` table contains 40 lacks rows.So i need a optimized select query for this.Can anyone help on this.Here is table schema&sample data for the trip_table..

[SQlFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efbdf)

Comment: what shud be the sample output you are expecting here?

Comment: output should contains fields trip_paramid,fuel_content,creation_time&vehicle_id.if we take difference of "creation_time" fields of subsequent rows(ie in output),then it should be approximately 2 minutes.

Comment: @vmb Assume row 1 contain 2012-11-08 01:21:37 and second row contain 2012-11-08 01:25:37 . Here time difference is more than 2 min . So which one should i display 2012-11-08 01:21:37 or 2012-11-08 01:25:37 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    tp.*
FROM 
    trip_parameters tp
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(UNIX_TIMESTAMP (tp.creation_time)/(2*60), unsigned)
ORDER BY
    tp.creation_time asc
```

Note that using UNIX_TIMESTAMP does not allow you to handle dates beyond year 2037. Using the following instead fixes the problem:

```
CONVERT(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',tp.creation_time)/(2*60), unsigned)
```

Comment: query is working..as i mentioned in question,is it an optimized query??

Comment: The query itself is simple and does not really have a bottleneck built-in. The most important thing for you is to make sure your table has proper indices (in your case especially column: creation_time since you are most probably fetching data by limiting results by creation_time). I'm actually working on a project that handles large amounts of real-time machine measurement data and proper indices are paramount (well, for any DB).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one table scan using [MYSQL User defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Unfortunately UDV's have a limited set of data types (integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string). So in this query I use a char `@ti` varible to store previous datetime using CAST to compare it with the `Creation_time` field. Also initial value for this variable I set to (now()-10000000) you can use any date you wish less than MIN(Creation_time)

Here is the [SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efbdf/82)

```
select * from
(
select trip_parameters.*, 
if(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Creation_time,cast(@ti as datetime)))>=2,1,0) t,
@ti:=if(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,Creation_time,cast(@ti as datetime)))>=2,
                             cast(Creation_time as char(100)),@ti)
from trip_parameters,
     (select @ti:=cast(now()-10000000 as char(100))) a
order by creation_time
) t2
where T=1
order by creation_time
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT trip_paramid, fuel_content, creation_time, vehicle_id
FROM trip_parameters
GROUP BY FLOOR(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(creation_time)/120)
```

This takes one item of every 2 minute block

Comment: i think this answer is wrong because when i execute above query i got 2012-11-08 01:21:37 ,2012-11-08 01:22:37 difference between those two is not two minutes. Please correct your answer

Comment: Yes, this takes one value out from every 2 minute block, Block barrier is 2012-11-08 01:22 so the first value is from different block than the next. I think my answer is quite similar to heikkim's correct answer, only rounding of times is different and I didn't order numbers.